# Unique index or primary key violation while trying to map Map<Integer,String> in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, h2

i am using H2 embedded db and Hibernate 5. I am trying trying to map a HashMap in hibernate this way:

```
@Entity
public class TestMapping
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;


    @ElementCollection
    private Map<Integer,String> map = new HashMap<>();


}
```

Then i persist TestMapping object contains few pair key-value. When i am trying to see the result in Intellij by executing something like this:

`SELECT t.* FROM PUBLIC.TESTMAPPING t LIMIT 501`

i am getting this error:

[`23505][23505] Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY KEY ON """".PAGE_INDEX"; SQL statement: ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.TESTMAPPING_MAP ADD CONSTRAINT PUBLIC.FK8CYRSMJWNRD21DCB8T901RHA0 FOREIGN KEY(TESTMAPPING_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.TESTMAPPING(ID) NOCHECK [23505-176]`

I tryied to add `@MapKeyColumn` nothing work.

mydb.trace.db contains:

`10-09 13:38:28 database: ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.TESTMAPPING_IMAGES ADD CONSTRAINT PUBLIC.FK9V996C496B8GCB45MJI7WDA0D FOREIGN KEY(TESTMAPPING_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.TESTMAPPING(ID) NOCHECK
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY KEY ON """".PAGE_INDEX"; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.TESTMAPPING_IMAGES ADD CONSTRAINT PUBLIC.FK9V996C496B8GCB45MJI7WDA0D FOREIGN KEY(TESTMAPPING_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.TESTMAPPING(ID) NOCHECK [23505-176]
10-09 13:38:29 database: ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.TESTMAPPING_IMAGES ADD CONSTRAINT PUBLIC.FK9V996C496B8GCB45MJI7WDA0D FOREIGN KEY(TESTMAPPING_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.TESTMAPPING(ID) NOCHECK
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY KEY ON """".PAGE_INDEX"; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.TESTMAPPING_IMAGES ADD CONSTRAINT PUBLIC.FK9V996C496B8GCB45MJI7WDA0D FOREIGN KEY(TESTMAPPING_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.TESTMAPPING(ID) NOCHECK [23505-176]`

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a bug in 1.3.176 version of h2 console.
 As suggested [here](https://github.com/geonetwork/core-geonetwork/issues/916), upgrading to newer h2 release might help.